# Inject global response header before sending the response to the client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am new to spring cloud gateway and is trying to build up my api management.

I am using Global Filter to log the incoming uri and also the routing uri -

```
@Component
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements GlobalFilter {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        String originalUri = exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString();
        Route route = exchange.getAttribute(GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR);
        URI routeUri = exchange.getAttribute(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR);
        log.info("Incoming request " + originalUri + " is routed to id: " + route.getId()
                + ", uri:" + routeUri+" with id:"+ exchange.getRequest().getId());
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

I can see this exchange.getRequest().getId() which seems to be unique for each request.

I want to add this id as a response header to all the responses before sending my request, but not sure how to add this as part of Global Filter

Please suggest

Comment: did you try setting a response before calling **return chain.filter(exchange);** , It might work as it same object .

Comment: You need to obtain the response from the server web exchange and then add the header to it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be as simple as adding -

```
        String id = exchange.getRequest().getId();
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("id",id);
```